# ACF Pro new fields returning NULL

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a site with some existing ACF fields which work just fine and return data as expected. I can add new custom fields and can save data into those fields but they return null in the front end. This isnt exclusive to any particular type of field and affects everything from oembed through to simple text areas.

Has anyone come across this before? Could it be a mysql issue?

Comment: Can you share the code you are using to fetch the values please?

Comment: My guess is that you are using names and not keys. Try keys, it not readable but works. The documentation even states that (at least) for first time usage you *must* use keys. This is my *guess* w/o seeing code... :-)

Comment: `echo(get_field('prep_time'));` works fine as 'prep_time' is a prexisting field however `echo(get_field('test_field'));` doesn't. `var_dump` returns NULL for the latter

Comment: I think I've resolved this. I'm running a translation plugin called Weglot. Disabling this and resaving the custom field returns the data.